# Transpile Common JS modules to AMD with return statement

Tags: javascript, amd, babeljs, commonjs, transpiler

I have a commonjs module I need to transpile to the AMD / requirejs format to integrate it in a larger codebase.

I am using gulp + babel to build, and so far I have tried using the [babel plugin](https://github.com/babel/babel/tree/master/packages/babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-amd)

The problem is that for this input:

```
export default 42;
```

the output is

```
define(["exports"], function (exports) {

 "use strict";


 Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", {
   value: true
  });

  exports.default = 42;
});
```

*(this is the basic example on the doc)*

Requirejs modules have to "return" what they want to export, so I will need an output like this

```
define([], function () {

  return 42;

});
```

It is possible somehow? I would like to avoid changing the build chain just for a couple of modules.